# How to add "select all" to combo in vb6?

Tags: oracle, vb6

I wrote this function for selecting all values at option "select all"

```
Private Function Not_Null()
   If CmbGrade.Text = "SELECT ALL" Then
      sql = "SELECT  A.ROLLNO,A.FIRST_NAME,A.MIDDLE_NAME,A.LAST_NAME,A.ADDRESS,A.GRADE,B.DIV,A.BLOOD_GROUP,C.HOUSE,A.DATE_OF_BIRTH,A.TRANSPORT,A.SNAME,A.MEAL,A.RUTNO FROM STUDENT_RECORD_DATABASE A,DIVISION B,HNM C WHERE A.DIVID=B.DIVID AND A.HID=C.HID AND GRADE IS NOT NULL"            
      SET rs = cn.Execute(sql)
   End If
End Function
```

After I called this function at command click

```
Private Sub CmdReport_Click()
   Dim STRp As String
   STRp = Not_Null()
   sql = "SELECT A.ROLLNO,A.FIRST_NAME,A.MIDDLE_NAME,A.LAST_NAME,A.ADDRESS,A.GRADE,B.DIV,A.BLOOD_GROUP,C.HOUSE,A.DATE_OF_BIRTH,A.TRANSPORT,A.SNAME,A.MEAL,A.RUTNO FROM STUDENT_RECORD_DATABASE A,DIVISION B,HNM C WHERE A.DIVID=B.DIVID AND A.HID=C.HID"
   Set rs = cn.Execute(sql)
   Set DataReport2.DataSource = rs
   DataReport2.Show
End Sub
```

When I choose "select all" option it doesn't show any record
Please help..........

Comment: Have you tried running these queries outside of your code to make sure they return something?

Comment: I have tried to run in oracle and they worked.................

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't matter that you're executing `STRp = Not_Null()`, because (a) `Not_Null` doesn't return a value and (b) even though you're doing a `SET rs` in `Not_Null`, then even assuming you've declared `rs` somewhere in your module or form, you're just overwriting its value in `CmdReport_Click`.

Try this:

```
Private Sub CmdReport_Click()
   sql = "SELECT A.ROLLNO,A.FIRST_NAME,A.MIDDLE_NAME,A.LAST_NAME,A.ADDRESS,A.GRADE,B.DIV,A.BLOOD_GROUP,C.HOUSE,A.DATE_OF_BIRTH,A.TRANSPORT,A.SNAME,A.MEAL,A.RUTNO FROM STUDENT_RECORD_DATABASE A,DIVISION B,HNM C WHERE A.DIVID=B.DIVID AND A.HID=C.HID AND GRADE ='" & CmbGrade.Text & "'"
   If CmbGrade.Text = "SELECT ALL" Then
      sql = "SELECT  A.ROLLNO,A.FIRST_NAME,A.MIDDLE_NAME,A.LAST_NAME,A.ADDRESS,A.GRADE,B.DIV,A.BLOOD_GROUP,C.HOUSE,A.DATE_OF_BIRTH,A.TRANSPORT,A.SNAME,A.MEAL,A.RUTNO FROM STUDENT_RECORD_DATABASE A,DIVISION B,HNM C WHERE A.DIVID=B.DIVID AND A.HID=C.HID AND GRADE IS NOT NULL"            
   End If
   Set rs = cn.Execute(sql)
   Set DataReport2.DataSource = rs
   DataReport2.Show
End Sub
```

Also, it's obvious that you're lacking even the most basic understanding of your programming language (VB).  I highly suggest picking up an introductory book on the subject, or searching for an online introductory tutorial before you go any further.

Comment: thnanx sir,but this executes only one or two conditions in sql but I have to execute a lot of conditions like "select all","select only one","order by various fields" etc ... thatz y I am writing separate procedures to avoid mess in cmbreport_click()

Comment: sir,can you please tell me how to "AND" various sql conditions for different fields on cmbreport_click()......... like <code> if cmbgrade.text="select all" and if cmbdivision.text="A" and if cmborder.text="order by last_name" and if cmbbus.text=empty then "select none"  </code> and many more to show in the same report ......... please rply

Comment: @cool_sari - look up how to use [string concatenation in VB6](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/joining-strings-vb6).  Also, you should start looking at parameterized SQL.